# Can I hide excess system logs?

Tags: android, android-logcat

Can I hide excess system logs? 
I used filter - show only selected application, but see much extra log info.[image]

Comment: I would recommend using `Timber library` for logging which can automatically tag your class with ability to use String format

Comment: I used this library https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo - it does the same

Answer (score 2):

You sure can.

I would suggest to add an Identifier (Can be your application name or some unique string) in the TAG in logger. When you have logs coming in, enter Identifier name in search bar which should filter out any extra logs.

Comment: I know this, but why system logs mark with my app package name. Is it some bugs? I enable filter 'Show only selected application'. But see extra log

Comment: It is not usable solution if I have legacy code with much log info

Comment: Its strange that system logs shows up with your app package name. If it could be of any help then use logcat from terminal and add a egrep command in pipe to knock unwanted logs.
For e.g.
$adb logcat | egrep 'identifier'